# How LINFIT in IDL is represented in R?

Tags: r, idl-programming-language

I have a code written in IDL that I want to convert to R.

within the code I found this function:

```
result  = linfit(dum_x, dum_y) 
 y_a= result[0]
 y_b= result[1]
           "LINFIT function" which fits the paired data { xi , yi } to the linear model, y = A + Bx, 
               by minimizing the Chi-square error statistic
```

I wonder if there is a similar function in R? Any ideas
How  we can convert this line to R :

```
       y_a= result[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is

```
result <- lm(dum_y~dum_x)
y_a <- coef(result)[1]
y_b <- coef(result)[2]
```

but I don't have access to IDL so I can't check ... you could give a reproducible example with IDL/LINFIT results ...